# How to configure windows server 2008 with two networkcards? Clients do not have internet access

Tags: windows-server-2008, internet

I recently migrated my windows 2003SBS to a windows 2008 standard server. The server has two network cards and has the DHCP DNS and AD roles. On the old SBS machine there was a wizard that helped nicely to configure one NIC as the internet gateway and the other to connect the clients. Now I am on my own and failing...
The server can access the internet, the clients can logon to the domain and browse one another's shared files, but the clients have no internet access.
How must I configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed [this](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/How-configure-Windows-2008-Server-IP-Routing.html) the other week when helping a friend out, specifically the Dynamic Version with RRAS.

If you have a simple network, you could follow the static path and it takes about 2 - 3 mins to get working.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually simpler than the article above stated. You need to first add the network policy and access services role, than go to the MMC of Routing and Remote Access and run  the "Configure and enable remote access" wizard. There will be an option to configure internet sharing through NAT that will nicely show the two NICs and offer to create the bridge for you.

Comment: I'd be careful with bridging, as you will need to be getting your IP addresses from your Internet connection and having all machines directly open to the internet.